# Change ffmpeg snapshot filenames using PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, filenames

I'm using ffmpeg to generate snapshot from an existing file, the command line is：

```
ffmpeg -ss 0:00 -f image2 -r 0.2 -s 640*480 test_%d.jpg -i media.flv
```

After exec the command line above the process start and will generate snapshot pics every 5 seconds, name start from test_1.jpg(test_1.jpg, test_2.jpg, test_3.jpg, etc).

But now I want the generated names start from test_0.jpg, and the step is 5(that is: test_0.jpg, test_5.jpg, test_10.jpg, etc)

Can anyone help me what should I do? (I'm using PHP). Thanks.

Comment: [https://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f](https://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f)

Comment: Sorry I didn't find answers from the link, but thank you all the same.

Comment: Yes! -start_number works! But now they are test_0,jpg, test_1.jpg, test_2.jpg, etc. How can I change them to test_0.jpg, test_5.jpg, test_10.jpg, etc? I tried add "-start_number_range 5" but it seems did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Cache your last number by saving it in the database or you using local file to write the last number reached in your exec and when you retrieving it back increase it by 5

```
//get your var from your database or from your cache file if it was empty leave it 0
    $mycachednum = 0;

    exec("ffmpeg -ss 0:00 -f image2 -r 0.2 -s 640*480 test_$mycachednum.jpg -i media.flv");

//save it 
 $mycachednum = $mycachednum + 5;
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work. Since exec is not in a loop but a single statement that generate pics automatically, so that "$mycachednum = $mycachednum + 5;" won't happen during the exec process. The parameter %d made the number auto increased. I wonder if there's anyway to calculate with the parameter %d? just make it changed.